# Unsigned int from 32 bit to 64bit OS

Tags: c, linux, 32bit-64bit

This code snippet is excerpted from a linux book. 
If this is not appropriate to post the code snippet here, please let me know. 
I will delete it. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char buf[30];
  char *p;
  int i;
  unsigned int index = 0;
  //unsigned long index = 0;
  printf("index-1 = %lx (sizeof %d)\n", index-1, sizeof(index-1));
  for(i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
      buf[i - 'A'] = i;
  p  = &buf[1];
  printf("%c: buf=%p p=%p p[-1]=%p\n", p[index-1], buf, p, &p[index-1]);
  return 0;
}
```

On 32-bit OS environment: 
This program works fine no matter the data type of index is unsigned int or unsigned long.

On 64-bit OS environment:
The same program will run into "core dump" if index is declared as unsigned int.
However, if I only change the data type of index from unsigned int to a) unsigned long or b) unsigned short,
this program works fine too.

The reason from the book only tells me that 64-bit will cause the core-dump due to non-negative number. But I have no idea exactly about the reason why unsigned long and unsigned short work but unsigned int.

What I am confused is that

`p + (0u -1) == p + UINT_MAX` when index is unsigned int.

BUT,

`p + (0ul - 1) == p[-1]` when index is unsigned long.

I get stuck at here.

If anyone can help to elaborate the details, it is highly appreciated!

### Thank you.

Here comes some result on my 32 bit(RHEL5.10/gcc version 4.1.2 20080704)

and 64 bit machine (RHEL6.3/gcc version 4.4.6 20120305)

I am not sure if gcc version makes any difference here. 
So, I paste the information as well.

On 32 bit:

I tried two changes:

1)  Modify `unsigned int index = 0` to `unsigned short index = 0`.

2)  Modify `unsigned int index = 0` to `unsigned char index = 0`.

The program can run without problem.

`index-1 = ffffffff (sizeof 4)`

`A: buf=0xbfbdd5da p=0xbfbdd5db p[-1]=0xbfbdd5da`

It seems that the data type of index will be promoted to 4 bytes due to -1.

On 64 bit:

I tried three changes:

1) Modify `unsigned int index = 0` to `unsigned char index = 0`.

```
  It works!
```

`index-1 = ffffffff (sizeof 4)`

`A: buf=0x7fffef304ae0 p=0x7fffef304ae1 p[-1]=0x7fffef304ae0`

2) Modify `unsigned int index = 0` to `unsigned short index = 0`.

```
 It works!
```

`index-1 = ffffffff (sizeof 4)`

`A: buf=0x7fff48233170 p=0x7fff48233171 p[-1]=0x7fff48233170`

3) Modify `unsigned int index = 0` to `unsigned long index = 0`.

```
 It works!
```

`index-1 = ffffffff (sizeof 8)`

`A: buf=0x7fffb81d6c20 p=0x7fffb81d6c21 p[-1]=0x7fffb81d6c20`

BUT, only

`unsigned int index = 0` runs into the core dump at the last printf.

`index-1 = ffffffff (sizeof 4)`

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Your first printf is likely the problem.  Depending on the architecture and phase of the moon, printf expects a `%l` value to be passed as two parm locations.

Comment: In general, you're trying to access memory that is probably out of your accessible memory range - `p[index-1]` is equal to reading from `p + UINT_MAX` location.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Hot Licks.

1) I change the %lx to %d, it run into core dump.
2) I comment out that entire line and leave only the last printf, 
   I still run into the core dump.

Would like to learn from you if you'd like to shed me some light?
Thanks.

Result:

On 32bit:
index-1 = ffffffff (sizeof 4)
A: buf=0xbf8297b6 p=0xbf8297b7 p[-1]=0xbf8297b6

On 64bit:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Thanks, icepack.

But it can pass without any problem by switching the data type from unsigned int to unsigned long.

From my understanding is, p points to 2nd element of buf which is buf[1]. So, p[index-1] should have no problem to access the 1st element of buf. 

However, I am not very clear on the data conversion among array index, unsigned integer and -1 as I think this might be this could be the reason leading to the problem...

Comment: Printing the result of `sizeof` using `%d` is undefined behavior. Use `%zu` for formatting an object of type `size_t`.

Comment: P.S. Lessons on development of 64-bit C/C++ applications: http://www.viva64.com/en/l/

Comment: 1) `"index-1 = %lx (sizeof %d)\n"` --> `"index-1 = %x (sizeof %zu)\n"`.  A well enabled compiler would warn about this.  2) `p[index-1]` is undefined behavior.  Attempting to access memory not known to be valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Arithmetic on unsigned values is always defined, in terms of wrap-around. E.g. `(unsigned)-1` is the same as `UINT_MAX`. So an expression like

```
p + (0u-1)
```

is equivalent to

```
p + UINT_MAX
```

(`&p[0u-1]` is equivalent to `&*(p + (0u-1))` and `p + (0u-1)`).

Maybe this is easier to understand if we replace the pointers with unsigned integer types. Consider:

```
uint32_t p32; // say, this is a 32-bit "pointer"
uint64_t p64; // a 64-bit "pointer"
```

Assuming 16, 32, and 64 bit for `short`, `int`, and `long`, respectively (entries on the same line equal):

```
p32 + (unsigned short)-1    p32 + USHRT_MAX     p32 + (UINT_MAX>>16)
p32 + (0u-1)                p32 + UINT_MAX      p32 - 1
p32 + (0ul-1)               p32 + ULONG_MAX     p32 + UINT_MAX          p32 - 1

p64 + (0u-1)                p64 + UINT_MAX
p64 + (0ul-1)               p64 + ULONG_MAX     p64 - 1
```

You can always replace operands of addition, subtraction and multiplication on unsigned types by something congruent [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) the maximum value + 1. For example,

> -1 ☰ ffffffff<sub>hex</sub> mod 2<sup>32</sup>

(ffffffff<sub>hex</sub> is 2<sup>32</sup>-1 or `UINT_MAX`), and also

> ffffffffffffffff<sub>hex</sub> ☰ ffffffff<sub>hex</sub> mod 2<sup>32</sup>

(for a 32-bit unsigned type you can always truncate to the least-significant 8 hex-digits).

**Your examples:**

*32-bit*

- `unsigned short index = 0;`

In `index - 1`, index is promoted to `int`. The result has type `int` and value -1 (which is negative). Same for `unsigned char`.

*64-bit*

- `unsigned char index = 0;`
- `unsigned short index = 0;`

Same as for 32-bit. `index` is promoted to `int`, `index - 1` is negative.

- `unsigned long index = 0;`

The output

```
index-1 = ffffffff (sizeof 8)
```

is weird, it’s your only correct use of `%lx` but looks like you’ve printed it with `%x` (expecting 4 bytes); on my 64-bit computer (with 64-bit `long`) and with `%lx` I get:

```
index-1 = ffffffffffffffff (sizeof 8)
```

ffffffffffffffff<sub>hex</sub> is -1 modulo 2<sup>64</sup>.

- `unsigned index = 0;`

An `int` cannot hold any value `unsigned int` can, so in `index - 1` nothing is promoted to `int`, the result has type `unsigned int` and value -1 (which is *positive*, being the same as `UINT_MAX` or ffffffff<sub>hex</sub>, since the type is unsigned). For 32-bit-addresses, adding this value is the same as subtracting one:

```
    bfbdd5db            bfbdd5db
+   ffffffff          -        1
=  1bfbdd5da
=   bfbdd5da          = bfbdd5da
```

(Note the wrap-around/truncation.) For 64-bit addresses, however:

```
    00007fff b81d6c21
+            ffffffff
=   00008000 b81d6c20
```

with no wrap-around. This is trying to access an invalid address, so you get a segfault.

Maybe have a look at [2’s complement on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

---

Under my 64-bit Linux, using a specifier expecting a 32-bit value while passing a 64-bit type (and the other way round) seems to “work”, only the 32 least-significant bits are read. But use the correct ones. `lx` expects an `unsigned long`, unmodified `x` an `unsigned int`, `hx` an `unsigned short` (an `unsigned short` is promoted to `int` when passed to `printf` (it’s passed as a variable argument), due to *default argument promotions*). The length modifier for `size_t` is `z`, as in `%zu`:

```
printf("index-1 = %lx (sizeof %zu)\n", (unsigned long)(index-1), sizeof(index-1));
```

(The conversion to `unsigned long` doesn’t change the value of an `unsigned int`, `unsigned short`, or `unsigned char` expression.)

`sizeof(index-1)` could also have been written as `sizeof(+index)`, the only effect on the size of the expression are the usual arithmetic conversions, which are also triggered by unary `+`.

Comment: Not almost always, just always.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I hesitated writing that, it may lead to the misinterpretation, that e.g. `1u << 32` would be defined to evaluate to `0` for 32-bit integers, but it is UB. Do you have a suggestion for a clearer wording, without the need to bloat the answer with unrelated topics?

Comment: Go for arithmetic. Bit-shifting is not arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks your comments @mafso. 
What I am confused is that 
 `p + (0u -1) == p + UINT_MAX` when index is unsigned int.

BUT,

 `p + (0ul - 1) == p[-1]` when index is unsigned long.

I get stuck at here.

Comment: Conversions are defined to be value-preserving. If that's not possible, for unsigned target types there's wrap-around, for signed target types you get implementation-defined value or signal.

Comment: @mafso: I do really appreciate your help to clear part of my confusion as it is clear to me that what the value it should be between 32 bit and 64bit. However, I made some changes according to your good information. It turns out some interesting result. unsigned short type of index variable can work on both 32 bit and 64 bit OS but unsigned int can not... it is really weird..

Comment: @rickhau: Does this edited post answer your question? I also don't really see what parts of this post may be superfluous, but it seems unnecessarily long now. Any input on that would be appreciated!

Comment: @masfso: Thanks for your great and detail explanation. Sorry for the late feedback as I am not aware of a new edited update. Your new post is more clear. Thanks for pointing out the wrap-around where I was stuck at. This is really a great post! Thanks again, masfso!

Comment: sorry  I was using mobile to vote another question but not aware of clicking the unaccept on this one. Weird phone.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not lie to the compiler!**

Passing `printf` an `int` where it expects a `long` (`%ld`) is undefined behavior.
(Creating a pointer pointing outside any valid object (and not just behind one) is UB too...)

Correct the format specifiers and the pointer arithmetic (that includes indexing as a special case) and everything will work.

<sub>UB includes "It works as expected" as well as "Catastrophic failure".</sub>

BTW: If you politely ask your compiler for all warnings, it would warn you. Use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

One other problem is code has is in your `printf()`:

```
  printf("index-1 = %lx (sizeof %d)\n", index-1, sizeof(index-1));
```

Lets simplify:

```
int i = 100;
print("%lx", i-1);
```

You are telling `printf` here is a `long` but in reality you are sending an `int`. clang does tell you the corrent warning (I think gcc should also spit the correct waring). See:

```
test1.c:6:19: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
printf("%lx", i - 100);
        ~~~   ^~~~~~~
        %x   
1 warning generated.
```

Solution is simple: you need to pass a long to `printf` or tell `printf` to print an `int`:

```
printf("%lx", (long)(i-100) );
printf("%x", i-100);
```

You got luck on 32bit and your app did not crash. Porting it to 64bit revealed a bug in your code and you can now fix it.

Comment: That's correct, but not OP's question, which is about the second `printf`. @rickhau: Another reason for providing minimal examples and not updating questions via comments (but editing the question itself).

Comment: @mafso Yes, I saw that. Thanks. I updated the working on my response as even tough it does not fix the exact crash, this is something else that can go wrong (for example - if there are some variables pushed to the stack after the int, `printf` will not display them correctly).

Comment: Thanks, @elcuco
It seems that I still run into the core dump even I use %x instead of %lx on the first printf.

Comment: @rickhau Not unexpected - you are referencing an out of bound index in your array.